# PHP Conditional Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a small problem. And I am not sure why am I getting this problem. See what I did was I limited a page to "Public Member" and I want this page to be access Library members too because library members would have access to all pages. So what I did was I added a simple condition like this:

```
if ( $user_role == "library-Member"  && $pageLevel == "public-member" ) {
    $displayPost = "true";
}
```

And in my post I added this condition

```
if ( $displayPost == "true" ) {
   .. execute html stuff ..
}
else {
   wp_redirect( 'http://sample.org/restricted-area' );
   exit;
}
```

But somehow the condition is not working. I have also checking `var_dump($displayPost)` the output is `true`

Can someone help me please? Thanks.

***EDIT***

**Image Samples:**
 1. [Sample 1](http://take.ms/ioS5r)
 2. [Sample 2](http://take.ms/J1kKA)

**CODE:**

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;     
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);  
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { $user_role =  array( 'public-member' ); }

$pageLevel = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user_type', true );

if ( $user_role == "library-Member"  && $pageLevel == "public-member" ) {
    $displayPost = "true";
}

if ( $displayPost == "true" ) {
?>
<div class="main wrap cf">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 main-content">

            <?php if (have_posts()): the_post(); endif; // load the page ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('page-content'); ?>>

            <?php if (Bunyad::posts()->meta('page_title') != 'no'): ?>

                <header class="post-header">                

                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                    <div class="featured">
                        <a href="<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); echo $url[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

                        <?php if ((!in_the_loop() && Bunyad::posts()->meta('layout_style') == 'full') OR Bunyad::core()->get_sidebar() == 'none'): // largest images - no sidebar? ?>

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('main-full', array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title()))); ?>

                        <?php else: ?>

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('main-slider', array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title()))); ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <h1 class="main-heading">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h1>
                </header><!-- .post-header -->

            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php Bunyad::posts()->the_content(); ?>


            </div>

        </div>

        <?php Bunyad::core()->theme_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .main -->
<?php
} else {
    wp_redirect( 'http://sample.org/restricted-area' );
    exit;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can we have the full code please ?

Comment: string *true* or boolean value *true* ?

Comment: tried both, boolean and simple text

Comment: Shouldn't `"library-Member"` be `"library-member"`, I'm just thinking that you use a lowercase `m` in `public-member`

Comment: Yea thats not the issue cyclone. It is library-Member. I told this in my post, `$displayPost`  is returned true but the other condition is not working

Comment: Okej, but are you sure you haven't mixed up how you're initializing the `$pageLevel` and `$user_role` variables? You have the following: `$user_role =  array( 'public-member' );` and then you check if `$user_role == "library-Member"`

Comment: Hi Friend, i can not see your `var_dump($displayPost)`. Where is it in the code? Can you please put your `var_dump($displayPost)` after this code `if ( $user_role == "library-Member"  && $pageLevel == "public-member" ) {
        $displayPost = "true";
    }` & then tell us what you see.

Comment: Check this out http://take.ms/ioS5r and this http://take.ms/J1kKA

Comment: Ok, so what is your code/page doing? Is it redirecting to another page? Like the last line you mentioned? `wp_redirect( 'http://sample.org/restricted-area' );
    exit;` . Is this redirection happening?

Comment: Yes, its redirecting to the restricted access page. If the user has no access to it.

Comment: Oh! ok. Can you like rather change your assignment & condition a bit `$displayPost = "true"`  & `if ( $displayPost == "true" )` and rather try a bit like this `$displayPost = true` & `if ( $displayPost == true )` just rather simplyfying it. Or Maybe something weird like `$displayPost = 5` and check `if ( $displayPost == 5 )` . We may not get to the actual solution but atleast we will see a different angle to it. We may just try to understand whether there is a problem with some string comparisons here.

Comment: Let me try and I'll give you a pic

Comment: http://take.ms/SavUa its working if I set it to `$user_role == "library-Member"` or `$pageLevel == "public-member"`

Comment: Umm... What happened?

Comment: Its still not working in the second condition.

Comment: Oh! What does this give you?  `if ( $displayPost != 5 )`. Try changing the comparison condition.

Comment: The page is not redirected to restricted access and runs normally

Comment: Okay I tried a thing. Let me show you the image

Comment: http://take.ms/Nd1QX

Comment: Yup so i guess its going into your condition. Just try checking which other place you are getting issues.

Comment: Try removing wp_redirect() from the bottom of your code and running it again, it might not be that line which is triggering the redirect. Instead of that line place something like `echo 'redirected';` and see if it still redirects to the restricted URL.

Comment: Nope, it displays only "redirect" on the correct page and does not redirect. I think its one of the wordpress functions in the post template

Comment: In that case I would rip it all out and put it back line by line. So start with just your conditional tag and the redirect. `if($displayPost){}else{ //redirect }`. With just that in place it should work correctly, slowly add the post HTML back in line by line until it stops working.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing